# CentOS 7 stuck at grub prompt after upgrading Kernel

Tags: centos, grub2, boot-loader, grub2-mkconfig

I tried to upgrade the Kernel using YUM and when I ran

```
[root@AFIBAMBOO bin]# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
No path or device is specified. 
Usage: grub2-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE] 
Try 'grub2-probe --help' or 'grub2-probe --usage' for more information.
No path or device is specified. Usage: grub2-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE] 
Try 'grub2-probe --help' or 'grub2-probe --usage' for more information. 
No path or device is specified. Usage: grub2-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE] 
Try 'grub2-probe --help' or 'grub2-probe --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.tecmint.com/recover-or-rescue-corrupted-grub-boot-loader-in-centos-7/.

Answer (score 0):

BTW

The problem has been [solved in AskUbuntu S&E](https://askubuntu.com/a/800613) and it introduces `grub2-probe` because `grub.cfg` after kernel updating scripts being broken.

Review your `grub.cfg` for lost indent and repeat `grub2-mkconfig`.

---

**Detailed description about updating kernel via yum:**

CentOS distributes kernel via RPM packages and stores it in own repository.

When you work with repository you install/remove/reinstall ... RPM packages.

RPM packages that stores kernel has **postinst** and **posttrans** sections that do all necessary steps to adopt new kernel in CentOS. This steps include several important things like **initramfs** generation, set new entries in bootloader ...

Lets see in [3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.rpm) postinstall sections:

**postinst**:

```
/usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel --install 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 || exit $?
```

**posttrans**:

```
if [ -x /usr/sbin/weak-modules ]
then
    /usr/sbin/weak-modules --add-kernel 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 || exit $?
fi
/usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel --mkinitrd --dracut --depmod --update 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
rc=$?
if [ $rc != 0 ]; then
    /usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --remove 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
    ERROR_MSG="ERROR: installing kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64: no space left for creating initramfs. Clean up /boot partition and re-run '/usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel --mkinitrd --dracut --depmod --install 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64'"
    if [ -e /usr/bin/logger ]; then
        /usr/bin/logger -p syslog.warn "$ERROR_MSG"
    elif [ -e /usr/bin/cat ]; then
        /usr/bin/cat "$ERROR_MSG" > /dev/kmsg
    fi
    echo "$ERROR_MSG"
    exit $rc
fi
/usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg --package kernel --rpmposttrans 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 || exit $?
```

---

These postinstall scripts using `new-kernel-pkg` script which is the part of `grubby` project. [man 8 new-kernel-prkg](https://linux.die.net/man/8/new-kernel-pkg) writes:

> Description
>
> new-kernel-pkg is a tool used in packaging to automate the
>   installation of a new kernel, including the creation of an initial ram
>   filesystem image, updating of bootloader configuration, and other
>   associated tasks

`new-kernel-pkg` script calls `grubby` (it's program inside `grubby` project) to update bootloader configuration. From [man 8 grubby](https://linux.die.net/man/8/grubby):

> Description
>
> grubby is a command line tool for updating and displaying information
>   about the configuration files for the grub, lilo, elilo (ia64), yaboot
>   (powerpc) and zipl (s390) boot loaders. It is primarily designed to be
>   used from scripts which install new kernels and need to find
>   information about the current boot environment.

Fragment of calling grubby from `new-kernel-pkg` script:

```
ARGS="--grub2 -c $grub2Config --add-kernel=$kernelImage $INITRD \
                --copy-default --title \"$title\$debugtitle\" \
                ${mbkernel:+--add-multiboot=\"$mbkernel\"} \
                ${mbargs:+--mbargs=\"$mbargs\"} \
                --args=\"root=$rootdevice $kernargs \$debugargs\" \
                --remove-kernel=\"TITLE=$title\$debugtitle\""
        rungrubby ${ARGS} $makedefault
```

If you need to know more specific info about how bootloader configuration are being builded you can run `new-kernel-pkg` (involving neccessary kernel version and parameters) with verbose mode (`-v` option).

---

So, there is no necessary to call `grub2-mkconfig` manually after kernel updating.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I now understand why it happened, but still not sure how to get out of GRUB shell now. Every time i boot, end up with GRUB console.